# How to change my desktop background image "forever"?

Tags: 12.10, desktop-background

I have a picture which I want to set as desktop background, and I want it to stay the background image even when I restart my computer (I don't want to set it every time manually, from system settings -> apparence -> background).

Please help me, I used ubuntu tweak for the login screen logo, but I can't figure out how to change the desktop background "forever".

Many thanks!

Comment: That is extremely odd behaviour. Normally it should stick if you went through the System Settings -> Appearance -> Background route. Are you logged in as a guest?

Comment: Yes couldn't belive it my self... I tried it and it stayed the same even after restart.

Comment: No, I'm logged in with admin account (the one with password)

Comment: and I assume you logged in as admin (root) after restarting?

Comment: It doesn't stay at me... I'll restart it again now, to see, but I already tried this for 3 times.

Comment: Yes I'm always logged in as admin

Comment: No, still doesn't work ...

Comment: Ok, there is something wrong with my ubuntu, if you say that this works on yours. I will try to reinstall it now, to see if it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: maybe try and remove ubuntu tweak and set your desktop background using System setting -> appearance -> Background... and see if that works. My guess is that the tweak somehow removes the background.

Comment: Wait, are you logging in as a root user and trying to change the background, or are you logging in as yourself and trying to change the background under root privileges? You shouldn't even be able to log in as root from the login screen as that is a massive security flaw. Have you tried logging in your account and changing your wallpaper, and restarting under the same (your own) account?

Comment: After I reinstalled ubuntu, it worked... i don't know why, but anyway, I'm glad it works now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you change your background:

1.Right click on the desktop, and click on Change Desktop Background.  Notice the purple background in the image below the menu.

[image]

2.Choose an image from the displayed images, or add one of yours by clicking on the + sign.

[image]

3.I choose the image that is pointed, and you can see that the background image has changed, and after re-booting the image stayed the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Solved. It is related to the use of encryption of the `$HOME` folder. The wallpaper is loaded before the login process, not after you log in. Therefore, if your wallpaper is stored in your home directory, and if your home directory is encrypted, the login system is not able to read it. To solve this issue, simple store your wallpaper image in a non-encrypted home folder, let's say in `/etc`, and choose it as default wallpaper as described above.